# User set custom date for their system Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime, browser

My web app (single page angular app) locks a particular page upto a definite date. (ex: 1 week from now)

user can view that page only after that date.

But currently if they change their system time to a custom date (ex: 2-3 months ahead) they can view the page now itself.

How can I avoid this scenario.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Note: This is not related to timezone issue.

Comment: Do the authorisation on the server. That way, users can't _change_ the date

Comment: I use firebase as backend, so I dont know how to use server effectively for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the client, you need to do that server side, this way it can not be changed.

Comment: I dont have fully functional backend. From server I only get a json containing the opening timestamp

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this can only be achieved on the serverside. As the user will not be able to manipulate the date there.

Comment: Actually user can see the page even before time, but with an over lay stating that this level will open at so and so time. When the time reaches, overlay is automatically hidden